# Android studio JSONArray cannot be converted to JSONObject

Tags: java, android

I realise there are similar issues but I wasn't able to find one with the exact same issue as me.

I have an API which gets SQL data from a SQL server, that data is then send to the client as JSON.
The API returns the following:

```
[{"text1":"value1","text2":"value2"}]
```

I am trying to parse both values using the following java code:

which gives me the following error:

> type org.json.JSONArray cannot be converted to JSONObject

````
private void jsonParse() {
    String url = "http://192.168.0.197/api.php";
    JsonArrayRequest request = new JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null,
            new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
            try {
                JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(response);
                for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject obj = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    String text1 = obj.getString("text1");
                    String text2 = obj.getString("text2");
                    mTextViewResult.append(text1 + ", " + text2 + "\n\n");
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            error.printStackTrace();
        }
    });
    mQueue.add(request);
}
}```
````

Answer (score 0):

in your method Parameter `onResponse()` you are passing a `JSONObject` instead of `JSONArray`. Convert that to either `String` parameter or `JSONArray`

Comment: I suppose you were right, this gave the following error: Not a primitive array: class org.json.JSONArray. I edited the post with the full code

Answer (score 0):

```
public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
        try {
            for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject obj = response.getJSONObject(i);
                String text1 = obj.getString("text1");
                String text2 = obj.getString("text2");
                mTextViewResult.append(text1 + ", " + text2 + "\n\n");
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    }
```

Do not use JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(response) , because response is already a JSONArray.